# How to extract date and calculate if it is within "x" days from today?

Tags: bash, shell-script, date, string, mailx

Currently I have file with structure as

```
Foo Sign: blah
    SubFoo Sign: blah
    BarDate: 2017-11-31
Foo Sign: blah
    BarDate: Never
Foo Sign: blah
    BarDate: 2016-12-20
Foo Sign: blah
    BarDate: 2014-12-20
.... and so on
```

This are the main four categories of data which resides in the file. Don't go with the `foo`,`bar`,`blah` things, those are not important. Main important thing is `BarDate` and its value.

## Main Part

**Case 1:** If `BarDate` value is `Never` I don't have to do anything.

**Case 2:** If `BarDate` has some value other than `Never` it has the format as `YYYY-MM-DD`.

**Requirement:** If the `BarDate` is within the span of 10 days from today it will mail to someone with it's details.

So, today is `15-12-2015` if there is any `BarDate` which is within 15th to 25th December of 2015 a mail will be send with it's `Foo Sign`,`BarDate`.

So a mail will be triggered for `2015-12-16`,`2015-12-24`,`2015-12-25`...

But not for `2014-12-16`,`2016-12-24`,`2015-12-26`

So far my shell script is

```
foo=""
bardate=""
outputfile="test.txt"
result=""
newline="\n"

### just a workaround step ###
if [ -f $outputfile ];
then
  `rm $outputfile`
fi

### filtering the date which doesn't have BarDate as Never, and writing it to a file ###
`cat datafile | grep -e "Foo Sign" -e BarDate | grep -v "Never" | uniq >> $outputfile`

IFS=$'\n'


### contains is a custom function which returns 1 if param1 is substring of param2 ###
for line in ${cat outputfile};
  do
    contains "$line" "Foo Sign" && foo="$line"
    ### constructing the result string ###
    ### -----> here I have to extract the date and see if it resides within 10 days span from today <----- ###
    ### then only the result string will be constructed ###
    contains "$line" "BarDate" && bardate="$line" && result=$result$newline$foo$newline$bardate$newline
  done

### mail the result ###
echo -e "$result" | mailx -s "BLAH" someone@example.com
```

Comment: What is `contains`?  You have not run this script yet, correct?

Comment: `contains` is a parameterized function, i found it from a [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829613/how-do-you-tell-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-unix-shell-scripting). I ran the script, currently it will mail all the data-set which have `BarDate` not equals to `Never`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get current epoch time with

```
date  "+%s"
```

You can also convert any time format to epoch time:

```
date -d "${MY_TIME}" "+%s"
```

And these epoch times you can substract.

Having the line with `BarDate: 2017-11-31` in a variable LINE, you can extract the date using:

```
MY_TIME=$(echo $LINE | cut -d: -f2)
```

Comment: Thanks, can you show me how can I extract the date from the string?

Comment: @AnirbanNag'tintinmj': updated

Comment: I am getting an error `date: invalid date '2017-11-31'`

Comment: @AnirbanNag'tintinmj' November has 30 days ;)